# What are the strongest boosting alternatives to Adaboost?

Tags: machine-learning

Whenever boosting is brought up, Adaboost is the first algorithm to be listed.  What are the most popular boosting algorithms that *aren't* Adaboost?

Answer (score 3):

[Gradient Boosting Machine](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/vignettes/gbm.pdf) - in my experience it always beats plain-vanilla AdaBoost (and it supports exponential loss function among others)